# rxjs5: defer creation of an observable until another observable emits certain value

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, frp, rxjs5

I'm trying to create an observable facebook jsdk, so I have a method, with `.create()`d observable that looks for example like this

```
getLoginStatus$() {
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<FBResponseObject>) => {
    try {
      // this._fb is window.FB
      this._fb.getLoginStatus((resp: FBResponseObject) => {
        if (resp.error) {
          observer.error(resp.error);
        } else {
          observer.next(resp);
          observer.complete();
        }
      }, force);

    } catch (error) {
      observer.error(error);
    }

    return function () {};
  });
}
```

the problem is, that since facebook sdk is being loaded asynchronously, it might still not be available at the time I subscribe to this method. So I have a `Subject` called `fbSdkReady$` I `next()` to `true` once it becomes available. Now the question is how to connect these, so when I subscribe to `getLoginStatus$` it first waits for `fbSdkReady$` to become ready and only then creates the observable.

I tried using `delayWhen(() => fbSdkReady$.filter(r => !!r)`, which works fine for waiting for `fbSdkReady$` to be ready, but the `Observable.create` is called immeditealy nevertheless and thus errors outs because `FB` is still not ready.

What can I do to defer creation of that observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `fbSdkReady$`. However if I understand you correctly it will only emit once the sdk is loaded once. This is a problem because if you subscribe to it later, you will have missed the load event and wont know if you need to wait longer or if it was already yielded. You should make the stream repeat the ready value once it is available. You can do this by calling `fbSdkReady$.cache(1)`, but since it is backed by a subject you could also replace it with a `new Rx.replaySubject(1)`.

Now we got that out of the way, you can just use the `fbSdkReady$` as the base for `getLoginStatus$()`.

```
fbSdkReady$.switchMap(() => getLoginStatus$())
```

Notice I used `switchMap` because it clearly communicates there will only be once instance of `getLoginStatus$()` active at any time. But since your source only emit once, you can also use `mergeMap` or `flatMap`.

Ps. I do hope you also call `complete()` on the subject and not just `next()`. It is good practice to signal Observables that you are done with them.

Comment: Ok, that was much simpler than I thought it would be. I was looking for complexity where there was none. Thanks!

Comment: @foxx No worries, many things in Rx are easy once you know the exact operators. Just keep learning and soon you'll know all tricks too ;)